# matching a whole line in python regex

Tags: python, regex

Consider this input in a text file:

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

If I look [in python API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for the re package I understand that if I want to match the `foo` and not the `foobar` I understand that this code should do it

```
import re

code = open ('play.txt').read()
print code

print re.findall('^foo$',code)
```

However the output reads

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import play
foo
bar
foobar

[]
>>>
```

Why?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) to your flags.

```
s = '''foo
bar
foobar'''
re.findall('^foo$', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)

Out[14]: ['foo']
```